# Using built-in dext driver with new VID/PID?

Tags: macos, iokit, ftdi, driverkit, macos-system-extension

[Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/implementing_drivers_system_extensions_and_kexts#3616855) says:

> If your hardware communicates entirely using standards-based
> protocols, you can ship a driver that matches your hardware to one of
> the built-in system drivers.

Is this possible to do if macOS itself has the driver implemented as a dext?

Particularly, I'm interested in providing support for an FTDI device with a custom product ID in my application. I've understood that macOS implements the FTDI driver as a dext (/System/Library/DriverExtensions/com.apple.DriverKit-AppleUSBFTDI.dext).

Comment: To clarify: do you simply want to use the existing driver but add matching for your custom VID/PID pair(s)? Or do you actually want to "extend" the functionality as the question title suggests? I think the former should be possible to do using a "codeless" dext. (Though codeless dexts do actually contain a dummy executable unlike codeless kexts.) The latter is substantially more tricky and probably not possible, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pmdj The former: use the existing driver for new VID/PID

Comment: I edited the question title to be more descriptive.

Comment: I have the same issue: use existing FTDI driver w/ new VID/PID -- were you able to find the resolution?

Comment: @AndriyGerasika Kind of. We made a request to Apple to add our VID/PID to their driver and now it supports the devices out-of-the-box.